# How to include a jar file in kotlin script

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I want to separate some generic code from my kotlin script file so that it can be reused.

I did this:

// MyLib.kt

```
package myLib
fun say_hello(name : String)
{
   println("hello $name")
}
```

I compiled this file to create a jar file:

```
kotlinc myLib.kt -include-runtime -d myLib.jar
```

Then I created a script file:

// myScript.kts

```
import myLib.*
say_hello("Arvind")
```

But i can not compile the script file as it neither recognizes myLib package nor say_hello() function.

What is the correct way to do this.

**Question Update:**
I am using kscript to run my script. Typing a lot e.g.,

```
kotlin -cp myLib.jar myScript.kts
```

every time I have to run the script, thus defeats the motive of using kscript.

Is not there any way so that I need not give path of jar every time command line. Instead I want to use it in a kscript way, i.e.

```
./myScript
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution using the kotlin command works. But this means that the documentation of kotlin is wrong: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html  This uses the kotlinc compiler to invoke the script and I cannot make it work to load the contents of the jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `myLib.jar` in the `classpath`, for example:

```
kotlin -cp myLib.jar myScript.kts
```

Also, you do not need to compile myLib with `-include-runtime`, unless you want to create a self-contained and runnable jar (see [example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#creating-and-running-a-first-application)).

**Update:**

Rename `myScript.kts` to `myScript.main.kts` and change its content to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kotlin

@file:DependsOn("myLib.jar")

import myLib.*

say_hello("Arvind")
```

You now can call it (don't forget to set execute permissions):

```
./myScript.main.kts
```

If instead of the `myLib.jar` file you want to include the `myLib.kt` script replace `@file:DependsOn("myLib.jar")` by `@file:Import("myLib.kt")`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please clarify one more thing. You said "Also, you do not need to compile myLib with -include-runtime". Is it true even if the jar file uses the kotlin standard library functions?? For example what if I am using time or calander functions or may be nio package.

Comment: @arvindpavariya I edited the the answer to explain why you don't need -include-runtime.

Comment: Please refer to the question update. I need a different solution.

Comment: @arvindpavariya Answer updated to show how you can call the script with less command line typing

Comment: Thanks @Edgar Domingues. It worked. If you dont mind, Could you please explain me the need of renaming the script file to myScript.main.kts. Because the *.kts files already considers their content as if written inside the main function.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. I think it's for Kotlin to include kotlin-main-kts.jar in the classpath, which it's need to resolve the dependencies (e.g. file:DependsOn and file:Import).

Comment: How to add JAVA_HOME/lib/tool.jar with @file:DependsOn()? It doesn't work well if path is dynamic